# Edge 15 throws error when using 'for ... of' on a NodeList

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge, nodelist

When looking at the [ECMAScript compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), it says that Edge 15 and Edge 16 support `for ... of` loops.

However, when I run this code:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test]');
console.log(list);

for (const item of list) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

```html
<div data-test></div>
<div data-test></div>
<div data-test></div>
<div data-test></div>
<div data-test></div>
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Edge. Instead it says:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'Symbol.iterator'.

As I understand it, `NodeList` actually should support it, right?

Here's a fildde to try it yourself: [Test it online](https://jsfiddle.net/ukqcfon1/)

*Can somebody explain the problem or the mistake here?*

Comment: Edge does support `for... of`. It would seem that it doesn't support iterators on `NodeList`s.

Comment: Have you considered loading a polyfill? This kind of thing is what they are best at.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Good point. I'm also considering the suggested solution which is like a polyfill but for this specific problem only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edge does support `for... of`.

It would seem that it doesn't support iterators on NodeLists. Not all array-like objects support iterators and I'm not sure whether there is any standard saying that NodeLists have to.

In any case, it's easy enough to get `for ... of` to work with them:

```js
const list = document.querySelectorAll('[data-test]');

for (const item of Array.from(list)) {
 console.log(item);
}
```

```html
<div data-test>a</div>
<div data-test>b</div>
<div data-test>c</div>
<div data-test>d</div>
<div data-test>e</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So I must use `Array.from`, thought I could avoid that overhead. Thanks for your help by locating the problem. +1.

Answer (score 3):

If `for..of` is supported but Edge 15 forgot to add the behavior to NodeList, you could polyfill it yourself with very little code:

```
NodeList.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length ; i++) {
        yield this[i]
    }
}
```

To answer the other question (is it defined as iterable in the spec?) the answer is **yes**:

The DOM spec [defines NodeList](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#nodelist) as:

```
interface NodeList {
  getter Node? item(unsigned long index);
  readonly attribute unsigned long length;
  iterable<Node>;
};
```

Note the third property, `iterable<Node>;`. Looking it up [in the WebIDL spec](https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#idl-iterable):

> In the ECMAScript language binding, an interface that is iterable will
>   have “entries”, “forEach”, “keys”, “values” and @@iterator properties
>   on its interface prototype object.

It seems that Edge doesn't implement any of that.

Comment: It appears that `Edge` does not implement `NodeList#values`.

Comment: Ah well, thanks for checking. At least then it is consistent with the DOM level 3. I will edit my answer.